# Ubuntu Firefox: site is displayed with super zoom

Tags: ubuntu, firefox

It only happens with [Stack Overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Overflow), so I think it's probably a certain key combination or something I did with the mouse without noticing.

How can I undo this?

**Firefox** 3.5.3

**Ubuntu** 8.0.4

[image]

Answer (score 4):

In Firefox under windows (so may not apply to Ubuntu), <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>0</kbd> will reset the size to standard. Do it once and it should stay that way. Any good?

Comment: same function via menus: `View -> Zoom -> Reset`

Comment: you saved my day